# Expectations of functions of a Uniformly Distributed Random Variable

Tags: probability

> Suppose that $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,2)$.
>
> A) Find $\mathsf E[X]$

I got that to equal to $1$, because $f(x)= \frac 1{b-a}$ (in general) so $f(x)=\tfrac 1 2$ (when $a=0, b=2$), so then for $\mathsf E[X] = \int_0^2 x\cdot f(x) \operatorname dx$

> B) Find $\mathsf E[e^X]$

I got that to equal to $3.1946$ , because for $\mathsf E[e^X]$ did the same thing $\mathsf E[e^X] = \int_0^2 e^x \cdot f(x) \operatorname dx$

I am wondering if these are right and if not could you please show me how to do it the correct way.

Comment: How did you do them?

Comment: f(x)= 1/a-b so f(x)=1/2 then for  E[X] = integral 0 to 2 of x*f(x) dx

Comment: for E[e^x] did the same thing E[e^x] = integral 0 to 2 of e^x * f(x) dx

Comment: I think you should leave it as $(e^2-1)/2 \doteq 3.19453$.

Comment: @BrianByrne I've moved your comments to the question's body and formatted with MathJax. Hit the edit button to study it for future questions.  Meanwhile your method is quite correct, although I agree with Brian Tung that it would be more informative to leave it as $\tfrac 12(\mathsf e^2 -1) \simeq 3.19453$.  Good work, though.

Answer (score 1):

1. The expectation of a uniform distribution is 
   $$\frac{a+b}{2} = \frac{0+2}{2} = 1.$$
   We agree.
2. The expectation here is
   \begin{align*}
   E[e^{X}] &= \int_0^2 e^{x}f_X(x)\,dx\\
   &= \int_0^2 e^{x}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\,dx\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}[e^2-e^0]\\
   &= 3.194528.
   \end{align*}
   We (almost) agree.